# How to show only columns with value greater than x

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a dataframe with 14000 rows and 80 columns, all binary entries (1s and 0s), see minimal example below.
I want to display for a certain index (row) all columns that have value >0.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np

dat = np.array([[0,1,0,1,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,1,0],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [0,1,0,1,0,0]])

df= pd.DataFrame(dat, columns = ["p%d" % (i + 1) for i in range(6)])
```

Expected/wanted output is to show all columns with value >0 for a specified index (row):

```
    p6
3    1
```

I've tried the following, it shows all columns that have a 1 in any row:

```
df.loc[df.index == 3, df.gt(0).any()]
# out:   
#      p1   p2  p4  p5  p6
#  3    0   0   0   0   1
```

Also tried `.all()`, which will show the column that has a 1 in all rows. These operate column-wise, not just the value at index == 3, probably because it comes after the comma, so I also tried this, gives an error:

```
df.loc[(df.index == 3) & (df.gt(0).any())]
# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (6,)
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

IIUIC, you could use

```
In [348]: c = df.loc[[3]]

In [349]: c.loc[:, c.gt(0).all()]
Out[349]:
   p6
3   1
```

Comment: Nice solution. Since you only have binary values I think `eq(1)` or `astype(bool)` may be more appropriate.

Comment: Two things I don't like about this.  One: by using `[[3]]` to define `c` you make it necessary to use `all()` later on to reduce the dimensions of `(1, n)` to `(n,)`.  Two: Though it's clever that the definition of `c` contains the index information `3` which provides a convenience when using `loc` in the second line, it also makes it confusing if you aren't intimately aware of how the indexing will resolve.  My two cents.  Still a good answer (-:

Answer (score 1):

Using `0` and `1` as `bool`

```
df.loc[[3], df.loc[3].astype(bool)]

   p6
3   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new series aggregating column names, then use the `loc` accessor:

```
def get_cols(row):
    return row[row.astype(bool)].index.tolist()

df['TrueCols'] = df.apply(get_cols, axis=1)

print(df.loc[3, 'TrueCols'])  # ['p6']
print(df.loc[1, 'TrueCols'])  # ['p4', 'p5']
```

The benefit of this solution is your results are calculated in one step. So repeated `loc` calls to extract `TrueCols` for a given index / row are inexpensive.